# Unable to obtain OffsetDateTime from String

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, datetime, datetimeoffset

I have to obtain `OffsetDateTime` from a string value

> "2008-11-15T17:52:58"

I have tried various ways but it gives this error. Please look at the below code snippet and error and provide the comments.

First way to try :

```
ZonedDateTime.parse("2008-11-15T17:52:58", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ")).toOffsetDateTime();
```

Second try :

```
OffsetDateTime.parse("2014-06-09T17:15:04+02:00", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"));
```

I am getting this error.

```
Text '2008-11-15T17: 52: 58' could not be parsed at index 19
```

Comment: What offset are you expecting from input with no offset info?

Comment: What does this have to do with Spring? This is a question about plain old Java's date and time library.

Answer (score 3):

Your pattern `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ` does not include zone offset to parse `+02:00`. This format looks like [RFC-3339](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3339) which is already pre-created in [DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_DATE_TIME)

If you need `OffsetDateTime` while your input has no offset, you should ask yourself what offset to use.

There is [parseBest](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#parseBest-java.lang.CharSequence-java.time.temporal.TemporalQuery...-) method in DateTimeFormatter that can try multiple temporal queries and gave you back what it found:

```
Stream.of("2008-11-15T17:52:58", "2014-06-09T17:15:04+02:00").map(s -> {
    return DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME.parseBest(s,
            OffsetDateTime::from, LocalDateTime::from);
}).forEach(ta -> {
    System.out.println("Type : " + ta.getClass());
    System.out.println("Value : " + ta.toString());
});
```

Here is output:

```
Type : class java.time.LocalDateTime
Value : 2008-11-15T17:52:58
Type : class java.time.OffsetDateTime
Value : 2014-06-09T17:15:04+02:00
```

As you can see, your first input `2008-11-15T17:52:58` has no offset info so it can't be parsed into OffsetDateTime. You can easily detect that and call `.atOffset(...)` if you know what offset to use

Here is modified version to detect missing offset and convert `LocalDateTime` to `OffsetDateTime` (if you know what offset to use)

```
Stream.of("2008-11-15T17:52:58", "2014-06-09T17:15:04+02:00").map(s -> {
    return DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME.parseBest(s,
            OffsetDateTime::from, LocalDateTime::from);
}).forEach(ta -> {

    final OffsetDateTime odt;

    if (ta instanceof OffsetDateTime) {
        odt = (OffsetDateTime) ta;
    } else {
        //here is 2-hour offset hardcoded. If you need OffsetDateTime
        //you should also know offset somehow
        odt = ((LocalDateTime) ta).atOffset(ZoneOffset.ofHours(2));
    }

    System.out.println("Type : " + odt.getClass());
    System.out.println("Value : " + odt.toString());
});
```

Output

```
Type : class java.time.OffsetDateTime
Value : 2008-11-15T17:52:58+02:00
Type : class java.time.OffsetDateTime
Value : 2014-06-09T17:15:04+02:00
```

Comment: What about ZonedDateTime.parse("2008-11-15T17:52:58", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ")).toOffsetDateTime();?

Comment: @s_k_t see my update. You can't just call `toOffsetDateTime()` on temporal with **no offset info** What are you expecting back from it? You need to provide offset somehow first, eg. using `atOffset()`

Answer (score 1):

**If you can get your string like `2014-06-09T17:15:04+02:00`**, then it contains a UTC offset, here `+02:00`, that is 2 hours 0 minutes. In this case you’re set:

```
    OffsetDateTime parsedDateTime = OffsetDateTime.parse("2014-06-09T17:15:04+02:00");
    System.out.println(parsedDateTime);
```

> 2014-06-09T17:15:04+02:00

We don’t even need to specify a formatter. The string is in ISO 8601 format, and `OffsetDateTime` and the other classes of java.time parse the most common ISO 8601 variants as their default.

**If you get the string like `2008-11-15T17:52:58`**, the offset is missing, so it cannot be converted directly to an `OffsetDateTime` since, as the name says, an `OffsetDateTime` includes an offset. You cannot assign first and last name to a person if you are only told the first name.

If you know that some known time zone was understood and intended, you may convert to an`OffsetDateTime`, though. If you know the familiy name of a person’s family, maybe you can assume that it is also this person’s last name? It’s probably easier to understand if we make the conversion explicit in the code. We first parse into a `LocalDateTime`. `Local` in some of the class names of java.time means “without time zone or offset”, so this is the right class for your string. And the format is still ISO 8601, so we still don’t need the formatter.

```
    OffsetDateTime calculatedDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse("2008-11-15T17:52:58")
            .atZone(ZoneId.of("Asia/Karachi"))
            .toOffsetDateTime();
    System.out.println(calculatedDateTime);
```

> 2008-11-15T17:52:58+05:00

The conversion takes any summer time (DST) and other time changes in the specified time zone into account.

### What went wrong in your code?

```
    ZonedDateTime.parse("2008-11-15T17:52:58", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ")).toOffsetDateTime();
```

Your pattern `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ` requires that your string contains three decimals of fraction on the seconds and a UTC offset without colon, for example `2008-11-15T17:52:58.000+0200`. One way to see this is to use the formatter for formatting and printng the result:

```
    System.out.println(ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("Asia/Kolkata"))
            .format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ")));
```

> 2021-02-13T02:59:04.324+0530

Since the string you tried to parse neither included fraction of second nor offset, parsing failed.

Your second attempt had the same problem. There still was no fraction of second in your string. This time there was an offset, but with colon between hours and minutes, which a single `Z` does not match. You might have used `xxx` for such an offset.

### Link

[Wikipedia article: ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)